# select2 noresult catch the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

1. How do I catch the user input and pass it to the create text field.

Current code shows `undefined`.

2. And the new term also not added to the list, the alert seem like not working.

   $.getScript('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.js',function(){

   $("#mySel").select2({
       width:'240px',
       allowClear:true,
        "language": {
           "noResults": function(term) {
           /* customize the no matches output */
           return "Create"
           }
        },

   ```
   escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
       return markup;
   }
   ```

   })
     .parent().find('.select2-with-searchbox').on('click','#addNew',function(){
       /* add the new term */
       var newTerm = $('#newTerm').val();
       alert('adding:'+newTerm);
       $(''+newTerm+'').appendTo('#mySel');
       $('#mySel').select2('val',newTerm); // select the new term
       $("#mySel").select2('close');       // close the dropdown
     })

   });

http://www.codeply.com/go/LxasHWd0rd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [select2 documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html), you can use the "tags" option to achieve what you're trying to do. Select2 already does that for you:

"If the tags option is passed into Select2, if a user types anything into the search box which doesn't already exist, it will be displayed at the top and the user will be able to select it."